# python raw input delete the zero in the begining?

Tags: python, directory

I use this code to create directories with the inputs from user but when enter the perfix like that
00 or 011 it remove the first digit and create the folders with the names "0 , 11"

```
#Asking for inputs
try:
    numRan = int(raw_input("How many Perfix you want to start ?\n"))
except:
    print "Perfix must be a number"
    sys.exit()
```

any explanation ?

Comment: You are converting the input to an integer.

Comment: how i can solve it ???

Comment: I've posted an answer. Also, you're probably meaning 'prefix' rather than 'perfix'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lines converts each line of input to an integer:

```
inpt = int(raw_input( "Perfix %d : " % (i+1) ))
```

The [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function ignores any leading zeros in the string.

But it looks like you could just leave `inpt` as a string in your case:

```
inpt = raw_input("Perfix %d : " % (i + 1))
```

If you only want to allow digits, you could use [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit).

Comment: `int()` may reject a string even if `s.isdigit()` is true (though `isdigit()` works for ascii strings). You could use `isdecimal()` for Unicode strings.